# If n>6 is an even perfect number, Prove that n is congruent to 4 (mod12)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, perfect-numbers

I know that for n to be an even perfect number greater than 6 it has the form $2^{m-1}(2^m-1)$ where $m$ is prime. I also know that since n is an even perfect number, it is congruent to 1 (mod 9).

What I have worked out is:
$n=9s+1$. Since $n$ is even, $s$ must be odd giving $n=9(2r+1)=18r+10$
So $n$ is congruent to 10 (mod 18).

I was hoping I might be able to use the Chinese remainder theorem on the congruences, but I see now that won't work. I have been working on this for a couple days and I am stuck! I don't know how to change (mod 9) and (mod 18) into (mod 12) or if I'm going about this in completely the wrong manner.

Comment: You know that $n \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$. What can you say about $n \bmod 4$?

Comment: Every even perfect number has the form $2^{k-1}(2^k - 1)$ where $2^k - 1$ is prime. Take it from here.

Comment: Ah!! Thank you both for your quick and helpful replies! I was able to work out, since k must be prime that k=2r+1 thus you have it in the form $2^2r(2^(2r+1)-1) which is congruent to 0 (mod 4). Since 4 and 3 are coprime, by the CRT I was able to get that n is congruent to 4 (mod 12). Thanks!